# How to select data in JSON based on other JSON data? Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to select certain data in a JSON Object using other data in the same JSON Object. Similar to MySQL. For example:

```
myObj = {"elements" : [ { "name" : "Hydrogen", "symbol" : "H" }, { "name" : "Silver", "symbol" : "Ag" }]};
```

I want to select "Hydrogen" where the symbol is "H". Instead of having to put in something like this:

```
document.getElementByID("TEST").innerHTML = myObj.elements[0].name;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Loop through all elements in the myObj.elements and checks and selects it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function to do it for you.

```
document.getElementByID("TEST").innerHTML = findNameBySymbol(myObj.elements, 'H');

function findNameBySymbol(elements, symbol) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
    if (elements[i].symbol === symbol) {
      return elements[i].name;
    }
  }
}
```

Better yet, if you have any control over the structure of the data, you could structure it like this:

```
myObj = {"H": "Hydrogen", "Ag": "Silver"};
```

Then a lookup is as simple as `myObj['H']`.

Comment: You are epic dude thanks so much. Sorry bout the dumb question, I just got back into programming/scripting after a 7 month break :/ Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases Tyler Hoilen's solution is good enough. If you have an extremely large data, you can try to convert your data to a hash table, which would provide a fast access to the elements. Just make sure that every element has a unique symbol.

```js
function convertToHash(data) {
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    hash[data[i].symbol] = data[i].name;
  }
  return hash;
}

var hash = convertToHash(myObj.elements);
document.getElementByID("TEST").innerHTML = hash["H"];
```